# Queria entender a saída desse código

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um código simples que recebe  mais de uma frase e coloca ela em um array de tamanho (quantidade de frases) N. Consegui fazer um código mas com o tamanho do array já definido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n = 2;
    char lista[n][100]; 

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", lista[x]);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        printf("%s\n", lista[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, eu rodo, escrevo duas frases e depois ele me retorna as duas frases que eu escrevi.

Eu tentei depois usar o scanf pra definir n, que seria quantas frases tem nesse array, desse modo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    char lista[n][100]; 

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", lista[x]);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", lista[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Porem quando eu rodo o código e coloco o número 2 no terminal, por exemplo, antes de conseguir escrever as frases ele simplesmente me retorna "►" logo em seguida. Eu to muito perdido, eu não faço ideia do que seria esse "►".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O tamanho do array precisa estar definido em tempo de compilação (ao compilar), não dá pra fazer em *runtime* (ou seja, quando estiver em execução), por isso funciona no primeiro exemplo, onde já está previamente definido com o valor 2.

É possível usar o `malloc` para mudar o tamanho do array em *runtime*. Veja mais aqui: [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)